# Chrome Windows goes blank - Large text, transform scale w/multiply background

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, gsap

I have a component built which allows a text-mask to appear over a video, for the size of the character to fit the viewport, the text scale can be incredibly large.

I am using GSAP to animate and JS to generate the starting scale required for the screen size, mac laptop works and Firefox/4k monitor works fine, but Chrome Windows cuts out until the animation progresses to a smaller size.

Please see my implementation in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ceddi35Pleach/pen/RwyMaBR)

Here is my JS

```
var scale = (window.innerWidth / 175) + 2.5; // window / character width + scale padding

var distanceFromViewportCenterToCharCenter = 350;
var offsetAfterScaling = distanceFromViewportCenterToCharCenter * scale;
var endScale = 0.2;

gsap.fromTo(".title", 
            {opacity: 1, transform: `translate(${offsetAfterScaling}px, 0) scale(${scale})`},
            {transform: `translate(0, 0) scale(${endScale})` , duration: 5,  repeat:-1}
           );
```

Has anyone ran into troubles with scales at this size? Firefox's performance on this was great, and everywhere else has been happy so far.

Much appreciated

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - in FF I say a few frames of the video and then the letterIs start to come in. In Edge/Chrome I see a white page and then letters start coming in- slightly part way thru. Is that the problem you are describing?

Comment: The prooblem is related to the size of the font. If you decrease from 1000px to say 250px you get nearer what I think you are looking for. An experiment of gradually increasing font size on FF seemed to show that it had an upper limit which was a lot less than Chome's so FF never actually renders the characters as 1000px. I cannot find a definitive reference to this. Hope someone can.

Comment: Hi @AHaworth yes, the issue is the frames of white prior to the video appearing - I am using a text mask animating in to reveal the text which should display the video fullbleed in those first couple of frames. - I'm experimenting with reducing the text size and adding a text stroke, to see if that helps chrome rendering or not

Comment: I think the point is that Chrome does render some huge text but FF starts much smaller. If you do a test on just one character in a div and increase the font size FF just doesn’t increase it beyond some limit.

Comment: Ah ok interesting, I am trying to work out a way to preserve the size whilst reducing the font itself, possibly with a different scaling method. I may need to swap to SVG for the text however that I think comes with its own problems when it comes to multiply+video backgrounds

Comment: Would transform: scale help?

Comment: Yeah, so transform scale is applied through GSAP and the calculation in the javascript - the scale is most likely the reason that the size goes too large on wider chrome browsers. I am looking at an alternative for using this upto 1920px as that scale system works, and then fading out the edges to look ok at larger resolutions, but it is a pity I can't render the text large enough with scale + starting 1000px size to cover the viewport in the center of the C character